# Use a dto as parameter in a native jpa query

Tags: kotlin, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following query in JPA, where I want to pass the `EntityKey` instead of multiple parameters to the method and use it in the where clause:

```
    @Query(value = "UPDATE #{#entityName} SET counter=counter+1 " +
            "WHERE id1=:key.id1 AND id2=:key.id2", nativeQuery = true)
    @Modifying
    fun incrementCounter(@Param("key") key: EntityKey)
```

Unfortunately the code above doesn't work and I get a `Named parameter not bound : key.id1` exception.
Is it possible to pass and use a Dto in the query instead of multiple parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[With SpEL](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions), you can access nested parameter attributes with `:#{#param.attribute}` resulting in :

```
@Query(value = "UPDATE #{#entityName} SET counter=counter+1 " +
            "WHERE id1=:#{#key.id1} AND id2=:#{#key.id2}")
@Modifying
fun incrementCounter(@Param("key") key: EntityKey)
```

Answer (score 0):

One Option is to use none native queries:

```
    @Query(value = "UPDATE MyEntity e SET e.counter=e.counter+1 " +
            "WHERE e.id=:key")
    @Modifying()
    fun incrementCounter(@Param("key") key: EntityKey)
```